# Accessing Image store in sql server "Image" data type from Android Studio in Imageview

Tags: android, sql-server

I want to show the images from SQL server "image" data type in android studio. My web site is already running in production and which is working fine in asp.net hence it is not feasible to convert the images in other data type as it will require large testing.

Pls help...

Answer (score 0):

Create another web service to access an image via a unique ID. When a client calls that web service, you should get the relevant image from the database, then convert it to some byte array format which a mobile client can use, then send that byte array as the response.